# Xcode Command Line tools to convert sqlite to coredata returning with nill data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, sqlite

I am trying use Command Line tools to convert sqlite to coredata .The Problem is  core data file created with nil data .The data in the sqlite is not copied into coredata . I followed http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated tutorial .

I Created a project in OSX with command line tools I added  datamodel .xcdatamodel file and entity files to this project later I added mydata.sqlite file in project->Targets->BuildPhases->Copyfiles.

My main.m

```
static NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel()
{
    static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;
    if (model != nil) {
        return model;
    }

    NSString *path = @"myDataModel";
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mom"]];
    model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]  initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return model;
}

static NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext()
{
    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
        return context;
    }

    @autoreleasepool {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator =       [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]  initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel()];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

        NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

        NSString *path = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments][0];
        path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];

        NSError *error;
        //NOTE NSSQLitePragmasOption
        NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };
        NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error];

        if (newStore == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        }
    }
    return context;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

        // Custom code here...
        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The sqlite is converted into coredata but the data mapping is not done.The coredata file created is with nill data .Can any one help me with this issue . Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is not precise enough. You need to state exactly what you are do and where you think it fails.

Comment: Please add some detail about what you're doing, instead of just linking to a long tutorial that might or might not be the same as your code.